# EhCache with Spring not caching

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ehcache

I have project which i have created using Spring framework. And now thought about caching some data for app. And i take EhCache library for caching. This link illistrate how configure it on spring: [Spring Caching and Ehcache example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-caching-and-ehcache-example/)
It works, but when i am going to change this lines of code

```
 ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
 MovieDao obj = (MovieDao) context.getBean("movieDao");
```

to

```
  MovieDao obj = new MovieDaoImp();
```

It is stopping work correctly. It calls method everytime. But i want to use second one. What is a difference? And how i can make so that second one to be worked?

**Added some piece of code**
My spring MVC project structure is below:

**Controller:**

```
@Controller 
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private BackEndService backEnd;

@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView viewDefault(Model model) throws Exception {
     model.addAttribute("categories", getCategoriesForGuest())
     return new ModelAndView(JspView.Home, model.asMap());
  }

 //@Cacheable(value = "categoriesCache")
 //first i want to make cachable this method. Not worked
 private List<Category> getCategoriesForGuest() {
    //i am going to cache method(guestListPaymentCategories()), but not worked neither.
    List<Category> categoriesResult = backEnd
   .guestListPaymentCategories()
   .getCategories()
   .getCategory();

   return categoriesResult;
}
```

}

**BackEndService.java**

```
@Service
public class BackEndService {
  protected WcfBackendService_Service service;
  protected WcfBackendService port;

  public BackEndService () {
        service = new WcfBackendService_Service();
        port = service.getSOAP();
  }

@Cacheable(value = "categoriesCache")
public ListCategoriesResult guestListPaymentCategories() {
    ListCategoriesResult result = null;
    try {
        result = port.guestListPaymentCategories(request);
        if (result.getResultCodes() == ResultCodes.OK) {
            return result;
        } else {
            throw new Exception(result.getDescription());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

If any working sample using Spring > 4.1 will be grate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create instance of object using `new ...()`, it's no longer a Spring managed bean - hence you lose all functionallity added by Spring, i.e. aspects (in your case - `@Cacheable`), transactions etc.

Basically, what Spring does is it creates a proxy for you object, which processes all the calls to the interface methods, adding extra logic depending on the annotations and aspects present. When you manually create instance of your object, no proxy is created, and all calls go directly into your object's methods.

Comment: Thanks for explaining difference of using of 2 methods. My second question is, how to make second way to be workable? Please see my updated post. I have posted some piece of code.

Comment: @AEMLoviji looks like completely different question. however, usually adding `@EnableCaching` annotation on your context configuration class, providing appropriate cache manager beans, and separating service bean into interface and implementation is sufficient

Comment: as i said on my first sample. where i am going to create an instance directly, not from beans it is stop working. and another parts i have not changed. What i need: to make project created with my structure to be worked.

Comment: you do not need to create instance directly. just inject `@Autowired private BackEndService backEnd;` where `BackEndService` is the interface and have `BackEndServiceImpl` annotated with `@Service` that implements it.

Comment: Vladimir, thank you for advise. Tomorrow will check it up. Will notify you about any progress...

Comment: My problem was key-generator. I have created custom key-genetor for my purpose. Because type of argument was Custom type on my method.

Comment: Thanks I was caching a method result in service layera and same service layer I was trying to call this method which was not working ... I moved caching to another bean and injected it to service now its working